# ace.js content doesn't show content

Tags: javascript

Running ace.js in localhost using the no-conflict/ace.js src from github.

```
<div id="edit" style='position:relative;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px;'>
        function(){
             this.id=5;
        }
</div>
   <script>
            var editor=ace.edit(document.getElementById('edit'));
            editor.setValue("var test='this is a test line';")
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");


    </script>
```

It initiates the editor, adds all the ace specific elements without errors in the console, but nothing is visible to the user. None of my elements are hidden so I'm out of ideas...

**EDIT**
Confirmed themes are loading and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline css is wrong.

Set it like this:

```
<div id="edit" style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px;'>
```

I assume you want it full screen so `position` should be absolute and you didn't set `;` after `bottom:0px`

Here you can see it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kkd34n05/

Comment: Hmm. I had to set explicit height and width to get it to work. Thanks for your help/